Tanstack V8 Filtro mediante Selectores
Estoy Trabajando con React
Estoy usando Tanstack Table. Para materializar unos datos que vienen de una API y generar un filtrador dentro de los datos que esta tabla contenga. Ahora el problema viene que estoy intentando filtrar mediante selectores una misma columna y varios valores
actualmente mi codigo se encuentra asi

const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = React.useState([])

const table = useReactTable({
        data,
        columns,
        getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
        getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
        getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
        getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
        onSortingChange: setSorting,
        onGlobalFilterChange: setGlobalFilter,
        onPaginationChange: setPagination,
        onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
        onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
        //no need to pass pageCount or rowCount with client-side pagination as it is calculated automatically
        state: {
            sorting,
            globalFilter,
            pagination,
            columnVisibility,
            columnFilters

        },
        
    })


useEffect(() => {
        // Función para convertir los elementos seleccionados en el formato requerido
        const convertirFormato = (array, id) => {
            return array.map(item => {
                return {
                    id: id,
                    value: item.value
                };
            });
        };

        // Convertir los elementos seleccionados de KeywordSelect y CampaignSelect al formato requerido
        const keywordsFiltradas = convertirFormato(KeywordSelect, 'Keyword');
        const campaignsFiltradas = convertirFormato(CampaignSelect, 'Campaign');

        // Combinar ambas listas de elementos filtrados
        const columnasFiltradas = [...keywordsFiltradas, ...campaignsFiltradas];

        // Guardar las columnas filtradas en el estado ColumnsFilters
        setColumnFilters(columnasFiltradas);
    }, [KeywordSelect, CampaignSelect]);


desde un selector le paso al ColumnFilters lo siguiente {id:"Keyword", value:"Aguacate"} esta funcionando el filtro y en la tabla mostrandome justamente todo valor que se llame Aguacate de la columna Keyword
ahora si le intento pasar {id:"Keyword", value:"Aguacate"},{id:"Task", value:"Recolectado"}  
pensaba que me entregaria todas las columnas que contengan en Keyword la palabra aguacate y donde Task todo valor diga Recolectado. vi que de esa forma no esta funcionando.
Mi pregunta es como puedo pasarle o como debo pasarle los valores desde el selector para poder filtrar cualquier columnas y que me traiga los valores que le haya seleccionado desde el selector
en el useEffect lo que intente hacer fue que todo los valores que tuvieran los estados donde estoy almacenando lo que desde los selectores estan siendo presionado. los saque y los ponga de la manera que necesita Tanstack para poder filtrar la tabla que seria {id:"accessorKey", value:"Valor a filtrar"} 
estoy usando la Version 8.
